# How to convert tensor dtype=tf.float32_ref to dtype=tf.float32?

Tags: tensorflow

I want to use the modify word_embeddings dtype from  `float32_ref` to `float32` through the function `tf.cast()`:

```
   word_embeddings_modify=tf.cast(word_embeddings,dtype=tf.float32)
```

But it did not work as expected and word_embeddings_modify dtype still tf.float32_ref.

```
   word_embeddings = tf.scatter_nd_update(var_output, error_word_f,sum_all)
   word_embeddings_modify=tf.cast(word_embeddings,dtype=tf.float32)
   word_embeddings_dropout = tf.nn.dropout(word_embeddings_2, dropout_pl)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dereference a `_ref` type using [`tf.identity`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/identity)

```
word_embeddings = tf.identity(word_embeddings)
```

Comment: You're welcome @user9799714 - since this answer solved your problem, please remember to mark it as accepted!

Comment: HI ,i have a another question ,How to convert tensor dtype=tf.float32 to dtype=tf.float32_ref?

Comment: You have to ask a new answer since is a different topic - but first remember to mark my answer as the accepted one